# All apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking

Tags: ios, http, https, ipv6, ipv4

1. what does mean by  All apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking
2. is it something to do with HTTP addresses and HTTPS addresses
3. also should I have to change API URLs

And please don't tell me to read the difference between IPV4 AND IPV6 Because I already did that

Comment: What does this mean? Can you give more context about your setup?

Comment: My app Is rejected by Apple and they saying we have tested your app on the Ipv6 Internet(wi-fi) Connection and it crashed. so I don't know how to resolve the issue ?? @NicoHaase

Comment: You must symbolicate the crash and fix the bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no thing to do with http/https/apis , you have to enable IPV6 in your server

Comment: Thanks, Sir, So I am using AWS so How could I do that ?? @Sh_Khan

Comment: Should I have to Migrate AWS To IPV6 ?? @Sh_Khan

Comment: according to this document https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ipv6-update-global-support-spanning-15-regions-multiple-aws-services/ it's enabled for some regions